# Unable to get the constraints right in xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I was playing around with iOS 8 auto layout and  constraints and ran into this simple issue, and wondering if someone can help me.

All I want to is to create view (uiview) and have a label at the bottom center. 
So I created a new project, Main story board is set to wAny hAny.
Dragged a view into it 
x: 16, y:20
Width 275, Height:560
Color : Green

Added the following constraints
Pin top space to superview
pin leading space to superview
Pin hight
Pin width

Added a label and centered it to the bottom of the view
on the label, pinned leading space to superview
pinned bottom space to superview

Currently not seeing any constraints error

using iPhone 6 in the simulator
in portrait mode, I can see the full view and the label at  the bottom
Now rotated to the left which is now the screen is in landscape mode. but the view is still on the left side of the screen vertically and 1/2 of it is cut.

So my question is how can I fix this issue so the view also rotate or I can the whole view with the label?

Comment: Not sure to fully understand your question, but if you're forcing the view's width and height, iOS will enforce these constraints, both in portrait and landscape modes. So a view with height=560px in portrait mode will still have a height of 560px in landscape mode, which could explain why you're seeing only half of it...

Comment: Playing around is not a good way to start out. You need to read the documentation to understand how auto layout works. I also suggest you watch the videos on the subject from the WWDC 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't want to be pinning to one side and not the other because as the view size changes (such as with rotation) only one side of the view will get pulled, and that's exactly what you're seeing.

So, either you should not pin and instead centre horizontally in the superview (and allow the intrinsic content size of the label to set the size) or you should pin both leading and trailing (so the label will always be resized to full width).

Comment: Also, if you want the label to be at the bottom then you should pin the bottom space, not the top.

Comment: If I set a width and hight of UIView, is it true that it will not get adjusted to fit different device? what I also noticed shows fine in iphone 6 portrait mode but not in portrait mode on iphone 4?

Comment: Don't set the frame if you set constraints - the constraints and intrinsic size define the frame